# How to run an infinate loop in thread in android when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to create a sound by comparing longitude and latitude with a value when value is 0. I tried this with infinite loop without thread.  But the program crashed. Then I tried with thread, but it also failed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    Button start,exit;
    GPSTracker gps;
    MediaPlayer audio1;
     Boolean button;
     TextView txt1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        audio1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.audio);
        button=false;

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(button==true)
                {
                    button=false;
                    start.setText("START");
                    txt1.setText("Press 'START' to start working");
                    audio1.pause();
                }
                else
                {
                    button=true;
                    start.setText("STOP");
                    txt1.setText("Press 'STOP' to stop working");
                    gps= new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
                    if(gps.canGetLoc())
                    {
                        double latitude= gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude=gps.getLongitude();

                        if(latitude!=0&&longitude!=0)
                        {
                            audio1.start();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wait for some seconds...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                audio1.stop();
                finish();
            }
        });   
    }
```

Comment: What exception you are getting.?

Comment: @Vijay: infinite loop, means infinitely using non-infinite resources. Does it surprise you, you run into problems?

Comment: While using thread I got a loop or something with handler exception I think.

Comment: couldn't see infinite loop here...

Comment: @Vijay what stacktrrace do you get?

Comment: I tried while(true) as infinite loop.

Comment: I think I didn't see any stacktrrace

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem, but I don't think you need the infinite loop.  The OnClickListener is effectively your infinite loop--it just stays going until the program exits or you stop it.

Comment: I actually want to start a thread when the button start is pressed. In that thread I want to run a loop to check wheather the longitude and latitude are zero or not. If not in each check  I want to run an audio audio1. This loops untill the start button(now stop) is pressed again.

Comment: Please help to do this.

Comment: Create a `HandlerThread`, start it, then get its `looper` and create a `new handler(ht.getLooper())`. Then in your handler, do the `while(true)`. Use RunOnUiThread(...) to play audio